# What is the distribution of the sum of logarithmic random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to derive the distribution of the sum of logarithmic random variables (for self study).  A logarithmic random variable is said to have the pdf:

$$f(x) = \frac{- 1}{\ln(1-p)}\frac{p^x}{x}$$

for $x=1,2,\dots\,$ and $\,0<p<1$.

We assume that we have an iid sample $X_1,...,X_n$.  I am interested in making a test using $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.  How do I derive the distribution of this statistic?  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is going to be a nice closed form for the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. I tried computing the distribution of $X_1+X_2$ using convolution and ran into a sum of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{k(n-k)}$ which Mathematica gives in terms of the Euler–Mascheroni constant and the polygamma function...